# Why there are no ad impressions on facebook audience network

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network

So the problem is that till 29th May my Facebook audience network was getting impressions but i don't know what happened after that, now I am not getting a single impression from last 2 weeks.

Can somebody help ?

[image]

**I have used Admob ad mediation and its showing:**

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: @Pratham found the cause ?

Comment: @AsadullahAli not yet.